# Add fragment with 0 containerViewId

Tags: android, android-fragments

Where does android add fragment when I call `FragmentTransaction add (Fragment fragment, String tag)`

I have written this code, but I can't see fragment's layout. It displays an empty screen.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(fragment, "test");
        ft.commit();
    } // onCreate

 public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup        container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
        }
    } // TestFragment
```

Comment: because, you are not define fragment container in xml layout or dynamic layout... this is reason. that you are not seen fragment in activity

Comment: First you add framelayout in your xml code of MainActivity and pass id.Framelayout id container which hold the fragment.example..  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new TestFragment()).commit();

Comment: I know that. I am asking about this method, it was used in ProgressDialog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify layout resource `ID` so, the `FragmentTransaction` can add your fragment to that resource (container).

When you call `FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment, Tag)` you actually calling `FragmentTransaction.add(0,Fragment,Tag)` and keep in mind "0" is not a valid resource ID. So actually your fragment is created without any view.

It is possible to have fragments without the view so this method actually is used for those types of fragments which just created to do some processing but have no interactions with layouts

Answer (score 0):

It adds the fragment to the activity state.

From the documentation - 
    public abstract FragmentTransaction add (Fragment fragment, String tag)

The method above calls -`public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

This method adds a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) inserted into a container view of the activity.

Reference - [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I have modified the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code :

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```