# add(Fragment fragment, String tag)-where is fragment added in fragment stack and UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

During fragment transaction we normally uses **add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)** which simple adds fragment to containerview whose id we specified.But recently I came across **[add(Fragment fragment, String tag)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))**.Where will this fragment be added in fragment stack and UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Android official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

> Calls add(int, Fragment, String) with a 0 containerViewId.

That means `add (Fragment fragment, String tag)` method calls `add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment,String tag)` with `containerViewId` value 0.

From Pooyas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36514283/1292557):

> "0" is not a valid resource ID. So actually your fragment is created without any view.
>
> It is possible to have fragments without the view so this method actually is used for those types of fragments which just created to do some processing but have no interactions with layouts

Answer (score 0):

Fragment represents the behavior or a part of the user interface in one Activity. You can combine multiple fragments into a single activity to compile a multi-panel UI and reuse a fragment into multiple activities. A fragment is like a modular section of an activity, which has its own life cycle, receives its own input events and can be added or removed with the activity being executed (a kind of "subactivity" that can be reused in different activities).

> Each fragment independently, such as adding or removing them. When
>   performing such a transaction with fragments, you can also add them to
>   a return stack that is managed by the activity - each return stack
>   entry in the activity is a record of the fragment transaction that
>   occurred.

so its added fragment stack.More details refer [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)